# How to get language in products using Woo Rest Api

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Using Woocommerce Rest Api, I can Get the complete `Json` easily, but this web shop is multilingual and products are in different languages.

How to target only products in a specific language?

There are also use three different currencies: **`USD $`**,**`GBP £`** and **`EUR €`**

The products Data doesn't Show which Currency is it. How to get the currency?

Any help or track is useful and appreciated.

Comment: **For the product currency:** on web shops that manage multi-currencies, the product is always set in the main shop currency. The customer currency choice is only available in for an Order, so Only for an ORDER (and the property is included for Orders in the Rest API.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i have get the three different language products but i need only english language products,In the json there are no option to get only english language .

Comment: I don't know about multilingual products and rest api and It depend on the plugin that you are using… Some plugins make a different post ID for each product from a defined language, some other no. If you use WPML, you should contact the support. For others I don't know.